# Joomla unwanted logout

Tags: php, joomla, debian, joomla1.5

I'm working on a Joomla project.

We made a custom component and in a specific view of it, users are getting automatically logged out. We got two modules, one for registered users and another one for the public(i.e non registered users). So in this view, I can see this two modules,  which is unexpected.

This view is made to show specific content based on the user status(registered or guest) and it's showing the content for registered users. I get the content for registered user but when I try to do some registered user action, I get the 'Not logged in' warning which is correct because I got logged out by Joomla.

Other views are working perfectly.

Do you guys know any reason why I'm getting logged out? I tried dumping JSession from the view and it's active(_state = 'active') and also activeProfile field is correct.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does it only happen on pages with your custom modules? If so we'll need to see the code from the module that is causing the issue.

Comment: The problem is only in our custom component view. I think that after our component view and registered users module have been rendered, the user is automatically getting logged out.

Comment: You're going to have post the code or a link to the site so we can see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

As i have face these type of error when I browse the component before completing the posting of form.

Just wait form some time for page posting then it does not logout you.